# How to back to the master branch in git?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have created a new branch in my project.
But what i need now is to back to the Master and create a new branch.
How can I do that with git ?

Comment: Are you looking for `git checkout master`?

Comment: `git checkout some-branch`. If you want to create a new branch from another: `git branch new-branch old-branch`. If you would like to create anew branch from another _and checkout_, `git checkout -b new-branch another-branch`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch back to 'master' with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417166/how-to-switch-back-to-master-with-git)

Comment: @wjandrea no , how can I back to the master (the origin) and then create my new branch from the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly check out master

```
git checkout master
```

Take latest changes from master

```
git pull origin master
```

Now, create new branch from master

```
git checkout -b newBranch
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
git checkout -b new_branch origin/master
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you could explain what this does. This would 1) Create a new branch based on the "master" branch with name "new_branch" and 2) checkout to the new branch.